# JavaScript hash of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have such type of array

How to access  `Viena`

There could be a lot of cities

```
[{"Viena":[{"date":"2018-11-10","time":"17:45","price":599,"to_city":"Viena","wday":"saturday"},{..},{..}],{"Paris":[{..}]} ]
```

Comment: Hey Bro, show us what you have already tried.  Then we can help you out.

Comment: i have tried to use map function for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` for this.

```js
var data = [{"Viena":[{"date":"2018-11-10","time":"17:45","price":599,"to_city":"Viena","wday":"saturday"}]},{"Paris":[{"date":"2018-11-10","time":"17:45","price":599,"to_city":"Viena","wday":"saturday"}]}];

var result = data.filter(function(value){return Object.keys(value).indexOf("Viena") != -1;});

console.log(result[0]);
```